# Reading from file Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, exception

I have a file.txt it contains like that lines:

- 461  480      0
- 461  494 0
- 461  496 0
- 461  524 0
- 461  527 0
- 461  535 0
- 461  551 0

461\t480\t0 they are seperated by tabs.

I want to read this file using java

```
String[] splits = line.split("\t");
int userID = Integer.parseInt( splits[0] );
```

It gives me error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "461"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Load the file in a text editor and check if there are any whitespace characters at the beginning of the line or before and after the tabs (most text editors have an option to display symbols indicating those whitespace characters). Or even better, debug your program and take a look at the string you try to parse.

Comment: I do it but there are no whitespece or any other things

Comment: try Integer.parseInt(splits[0].trim());

Comment: @user951487 You have something else in your `String line`, not the "461\t480\t0" value. Did you check `splits[0]` value?

Comment: There must be invisible characters in the `"461"` string which are not immediately apparent.  Can you pass the exception through `od -c` which is a Unix/MacOS utility which can translate binary characters to be visible.  Or maybe pass your input file through `od -c`.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
String[] splits = line.split("\t");
int userID = Integer.parseInt( splits[0].trim() );
```

I think since you are splitting on '\t', spaces are also coming with numbers so "461" might have spaces at the end. However `Splits[0]` must not be `null` else Null Pointer Exception will come.

Comment: what exactly is the string at splits[0], try printing like System.out.println("---"+splits[0]+"---"), so that we might know are there any spaces or what.

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains Windows-style line breaks, could you convert it to use unix-style line breaks (most text editors can do that), and then try to read it again. Also, please verify if the exception occurs on the first line, or if it correctly parses one line and throws the exception in the second line.

If all else fails, you should try to debug your code. If you are using eclipse for development that should be really easy, just set a breakpoint to the line after the `split()` method is called, and inspect the `split[0]` value.

Answer (score -1):

try to format your file like this

- 461-480-0

  461-494-0

  461-496-0

  461-524-0

  461-527-0

  461-535-0

  461-551-0

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\s+","");
String [] splits = line.split("-");
int userID= Integer.parseInt(splits[0]);
```

Comment: After line = line.replaceAll("\\s+","");  codes line becomes 4614800 and then it can not split("\t")

Comment: unfortunately it does not work it gives me the same error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "461"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at jp.ndca.test.MovieLensDataHandler.get5FolodTrainingData(MovieLensDataHandler.java:43)
 at jp.ndca.recommend.mf.SVDPredictorTest.cvTest(SVDPredictorTest.java:16)
 at mfTest.main(mfTest.java:17)